# Check whether parameter exists or not in the request

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-foundation

I have this function:

```
/**
 * @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 * @Route("/chequearFabricanteDistribuidor", name="chequearFabricanteDistribuidor", condition="request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'")
 * @Method("GET")
 */

public function chequearFabricanteAction(Request $request)
{
    $em       = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:FabricanteDistribuidor')->findOneBy(
        array( 'nombre' => $request->query->get('fabricante')['nombre'] )
    );

    $response['valid'] = true;

    if ($entities) {
        $response['valid'] = false;
    }

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

The function needs to be called from two different forms and the only different is the request var that holds the value. In the first form is: `$request->query->get('fabricante')['nombre']` while in the second is `$request->query->get('distribuidor')['nombre']` so I'm asking if the right way to handle this could be:

```
if (isset($request->query->get('fabricante'))) 
{
   $nombre = $request->query->get('fabricante')['nombre'];
}
else
{
   $nombre = $request->query->get('distribuidor')['nombre'];
}
```

Is this right? Exists a better one?

Comment: $request->query->has('distribuidor')

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As Cerad posted on the responses, you could use:

```
$request->query->has('distribuidor')
```

Comment: For those who struggle with `$request->query->has(...)` returning `null`, make sure you are not performing a POST request. For POST requests, use `$request->request->has(...)`.